# como hacer para que sea una sola linea

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo esta consulta

```
SELECT
  `presupuesto_annio_real`.`categoria`,
  IF(`clase_canal`.`canal` = 'constructor',sum(`presupuesto_annio_real`.`cantidad`),0) as constructorCantidad,
  IF(`clase_canal`.`canal` = 'distribuidor',sum(`presupuesto_annio_real`.`cantidad`),0) as distribuidorCantidad,
  IF(`clase_canal`.`canal` = 'salas',sum(`presupuesto_annio_real`.`cantidad`),0) as salasCantidad
FROM
  `presupuesto_annio_real`
  INNER JOIN `clase_canal` ON (`presupuesto_annio_real`.`clase` = `clase_canal`.`clase`)
  where `presupuesto_annio_real`.`referencia` = '200142'
GROUP BY
  `presupuesto_annio_real`.`categoria`,
  `clase_canal`.`canal`
```

y me arroja el siguiente resultado

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
categoria|contructorCantidad|distribuidorCantidad|SalasCantidad|
---------------------------------------------------------------
di       |200               | 0                  | 0
---------------------------------------------------------------
di       | 0                | 32                 | 0
---------------------------------------------------------------
di       | 0                | 0                  | 9
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

y necesito que el resultado sea el siguiente

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
categoria|contructorCantidad|distribuidorCantidad|SalasCantidad|
---------------------------------------------------------------
di       |200               | 32                 | 9           |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes *darle la vuelta* a la condición y agrupar solamente por categoría, así:

```
SELECT
  `presupuesto_annio_real`.`categoria`,
  sum(IF(`clase_canal`.`canal` = 'constructor',`presupuesto_annio_real`.`cantidad`,0)) as constructorCantidad,
  sum(IF(`clase_canal`.`canal` = 'distribuidor',`presupuesto_annio_real`.`cantidad`,0)) as distribuidorCantidad,
  sum(IF(`clase_canal`.`canal` = 'salas',`presupuesto_annio_real`.`cantidad`,0)) as salasCantidad
FROM
  `presupuesto_annio_real`
  INNER JOIN `clase_canal` ON (`presupuesto_annio_real`.`clase` = `clase_canal`.`clase`)
  where `presupuesto_annio_real`.`referencia` = '200142'
GROUP BY
  `presupuesto_annio_real`.`categoria`
```

Esto debiera darte el resultado esperado.

Answer (score 0):

En tu WHERE prueba agregando que sean diferentes de 0 asi obtendras el resultado que tu quieres sin el cero como el siguiente ejemplo:

```
where `presupuesto_annio_real`.`referencia` = '200142' and constructorCantidad !=0 and NombredeColumna !=0
```

Espero poder ayudarte